# Custom project type with Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm looking to make a custom project type with an Eclipse plugin where the files for the project are actually stored on a remote server but displayed to the user as normal.

I can handle connecting to the server to fetch the files and all of that kind of business, but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of how to display these sorts of things to the user in a project.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to implement a file system rather than a new project type.

Have a look at the extension point `org.eclipse.core.filesystem.filesystems`.

Comment: Looks useful, I'll have a read and give it a try. Sometimes it's hard to search for these sorts of things because of the vast terminology used. Thanks Tonny.